# Page break with every repeat loop

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am generating a pdf which group accounts first by Country and then by property.

For this i have used nested repeat tag.I want a page break for every country i.e. a page break for every outer repeat tag.

Please advice.

```
<apex:page controller="AccountSummaryReportController" action="{!loadKeyAccounts}" renderAs="pdf" >

    <apex:sectionHeader title="Account Summary Report as of : {!TODAY()}"  description="This Report Shows Accounts modified in last 31 days"/>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:repeat value="{!objectMap }" var="ProgNameKey">
                <apex:pageBlock title="{!ProgNameKey}" >
                    <apex:repeat value="{!objectMap [ProgNameKey]}" var="PlanNameKey">
                        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="grey" layout="block">
                            <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!PlanNameKey}" columns="1" >
                                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!objectMap [ProgNameKey][PlanNameKey]}" var="lstGrnRate"  border="1" columnsWidth="20%,5%,75%" >
                                    <apex:column value="{!lstGrnRate.Account__r.Name}"/>
                                    <apex:column footerClass="reviewStatusHeader" HeaderValue="Summary Status" headerClass="centHeader">
                                       <apex:image value="{! If(lstGrnRate.Status__c=="Red" ,URLFOR($Resource.Red),
                                                      If(lstGrnRate.Status__c=="Green",URLFOR($Resource.Green), URLFOR($Resource.Amber))) }" width="40" height="30" style="float:centre;"/>
                                     </apex:column>
                                    <apex:column value="{!lstGrnRate.Account_Summary__c}"/>
                                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                            </apex:pageBlocksection>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
page-break-after: always;
```

Css to break the page in PDF

```
            </apex:repeat>
      </apex:pageBlock>
  <p style="page-break-after: always;" ></p>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: This works.Thanks.But i am getting an extra blank page at the end.Is there a way to remove that.

Comment: You can use some `css` hack like if this is your last page then use` display:none css` in this` p tag`